# Hibernate / JPA returns list of nulls

Tags: java, hibernate, list, jpa, null

I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class OrderPackage implements Serializable { 

   @EmbeddedId
   @AttributeOverrides({ 
        @AttributeOverride(name = "pId", column = @Column(name = "P_ID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "prId", column = @Column(name = "PR_ID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "pin", column = @Column(name = "PIN")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "Id", column = @Column(name = "MN_ID"))       
   })
   private PackageId id;

   @Column(name = "MEM_ID")
   private Long memberId;

    .....
    .....
   // more fields and getters and setters
}
```

PackageId.class

```
@Embeddable
public class PackageId implements Serializable {

   private String pId;
   private String prId;
   private String pin;
   private Long Id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Mytable has the following fields matching for my query:

```
SELECT c FROM OrderPackage c where <condition> order by c.prId;
```

Matching records like this:

```
  MN_ID     MEM_ID       P_ID            PR_ID           PIN       ///some other fields
  6217      402022795    A1000005361     B1000077615     (null)
  6213      402022795    A1000005361     B1000037615     (null)
  6218      402022795    A1000005361     B1000087615     (null)
  6215      402022795    A1000005361     B1000057615     (null)
```

MN_ID is unique here.

I get the count 4. But all null rows in the list.

What could be causing this?

```
jBoss 4.2.x
JPA
Hibernate
ORACLE
```

**UPDATE:**

Is this still the case? (When there a null value for any one of the fields in the Composite Key, then it returns null for that entire row)

http://thelittlefellow.blogspot.com/2011/07/hibernate-gethibernatetemplatefind.html

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-177

Comment: SELECT c FROM OrderPackage where <condition> order by c.prId; should be `OrderPackage c`

Comment: Thats typo. Thanks for that.